# How to detect the database is backup mode or not in postgresql 9.4

Tags: postgresql-9.4

Currently we scheduled backup job at morning by using pg_basebackup. Is it possible to detect a database mode during backup time.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-BACKUP-TABLE) you can use `pg_is_in_backup()`

```
pg_is_in_backup()   bool    True if an on-line exclusive backup is still in progress.
```